# Store array to session storage with ngStorage

Tags: angularjs

I could use some help on how i could store an array to the session storage:

So i have a json object that returns this

```
Object
Objectauthority: "USER_ROLE"
email: "1@1"
enabled: true
firstName: "1"
id: 1
lastName: "1"
password: "$2a$10$qPjtVDxkCh3KaE2mr0.ZeuyyjceLy7JPVmelttVf7uekSQq01fZ9u"

but it has also returns a client list

clientList: Array[7]
city: "Brussel"
company: "John Doe's coffee shop"
country: "Belgium"
...
```

This is the angularjs code

```
$http.get('/api/getuser').success(function(data) {

    $scope.userdata = data;
    console.log(data)

    //Here we add all the stuff we need to the sessionStorage

    $sessionStorage.userid = data.id;
    $sessionStorage.userEmail = data.email;
    $sessionStorage.sampleString = "This is a sample string";

    //But how can i store the array to the sessionStorage ?
    //Is something like this possible ?
    $sessionStorage.clientArray[] = data.clientList[]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have it working i only needed to remove the [] So something like this works :

```
$sessionStorage.clientArray = data.clientList
```